# if condition to show Year, Month, Days

Tags: php, if-statement

I am a outside for the code writing, I have the below code is working.

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime("$date_of_dissolution");
$datetime2 = new DateTime("$date_of_incorp");
$difference = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo 'And the company is running: '.$difference->y.' years, '.$difference->m.' months, '.$difference->d.' days.';
?>
```

But I want to add one more condition, but the below code is not working.

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime("$date_of_dissolution");
$datetime2 = new DateTime("$date_of_incorp");
$datetime3 = new DateTime("$date_commenced_dormancy");
$datetime4 = date("Y-m-d");

if ($active_status ==('Live but Commenced Dormancy')) {
$difference = $datetime3->diff($datetime2);
} elseif  ($active_status ==('Dissolved')) {
$difference = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
} else {
$difference = $datetime4->diff($datetime2);

echo 'And the company is running: '.$difference->y.' years, '.$difference->m.' months, '.$difference->d.' days.';
?>
```

How should I modify the above code?

Answer (score 0):

If  I am not wrong you are forget to close curly bracket of else statement

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime("$date_of_dissolution");
$datetime2 = new DateTime("$date_of_incorp");
$datetime3 = new DateTime("$date_commenced_dormancy");
$datetime4 = date("Y-m-d");

if ($active_status ==('Live but Commenced Dormancy')) {
$difference = $datetime3->diff($datetime2);
} elseif  ($active_status ==('Dissolved')) {
$difference = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
} else {
$difference = $datetime4->diff($datetime2);
}

echo 'And the company is running: '.$difference->y.' years, '.$difference->m.' months, '.$difference->d.' days.';
?>
```